How springboot knows which properties files to pick in which environment
I am creating springboot application. Have three different environment. dev, pre-prod, prod. I need to create application.properties file for each environment.
I can create files like below.

application-dev.properties
application-preprod.properties
application-prod.properties

Now my doubt is how spring correctly knows which file to pick in which environment.

You can select one with -Dspring.profiles.active

Which means when running jar, we have to pass this parameter right?

@Gopinath yes. Or set it as an environment variable some other way. You can use SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE when setting it as an environment variable if you prefer.

When starting your application you set one or more profiles to be active. This can be done in various ways:
Depending on your exact architecture you will often set the active profile(s) as an environment variable:
java -jar example.jar -Dspring.profiles.active=oauth,prod

Other times you may instead have this set as an environment variable:
export SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=oauth,prod

Another option you might want to use is to have a general application.properties file next to the jar-File of your application and configure a profile to use there:
server.port=9090
spring.profiles.active=metrics

For more info check out this Baeldung article or this part of the Spring documentation!
